# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-2x}}{s^{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{e^{-2x}}{s^{2}}$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=u_{2}(t)$ , $y(0)=3$

$\mathscr{L}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=\mathscr{L}\left(u_{2}(t)\right)$

$\vdots$

$y=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{-2x}}{s^{2}}\right)+\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{s}\right)$

the right term of the RHS of the equation is 3. But is there a laplace formula that i can follow when i have to take the inverse laplace transform of the heaviside function over a term to the nth degree? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use a [*Table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), but if you've learned 
complex variables, you can use the formal definition for the inverse Laplace.

The original problem is

$$ \tag 1  \dfrac{dy}{dt}=u_2(t),~~ y(0)=3$$

We want to solve this using Laplace transforms.

$\mathscr{L}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)= s y(s) - y(0) = s y(s) - 3$, and $\mathscr{L}\left(u_{2}(t)\right) = \dfrac{e^{-2 s}}{s}$

Substituting and simplifying $(1)$, we get

$$y(s) = \dfrac{e^{-2s}}{s^2} + \dfrac{3}{s}$$

Using Table item $1$, we have

$$3\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{s}\right) = 3$$

Using Table items $3$ and $27$, we have

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{e^{-2s}}{s^2}\right)= (t-2)u_2(t)$$

I would also recommend reviewing this nice set of [*notes*](http://howellkb.uah.edu/DEtext/Part4/Inverse_Laplace.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It ought to be $(t-2)u_2(t)$ .

From #27 on this list:
[image: list]